# What is mongodb operator orders

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, mongodb, mysqli

How to define MongoDB operator orders like as who is first orders $lookup,$ project, $group,$match etc.

```
{
    $lookup:{
            //
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        //
    }
},
{
    $group: {
       //
    }
},
{
    $match: {
       //
    }
},
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking but aggregation pipelines are defined within an "array", which is a data structure with a defined order. The order of execution occurs in order of the array elements where each stage is defined. Possibly best to think of a "pipeline" as analogous to the Unix "pipe" `|` operator, in that output from the preceding stage is the only thing visible to the following stage. And so on, depending on what each stage actually emits. Things like `$group` and `$project` for instance only emit the explicitly specified properties they include.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are talking about Mongodb Aggregation steps on how it works,

It is like a pipeline we use in order to execute like, first pipeline result on that we will apply next pipeline and go on.

[image: img1]

You will learn more about stages/pipelines from this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

**EDIT**

```
$this->manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://$mongo_host:$mongo_port/$mongo_db_name", array_filter([
            'username' => $mongo_user_name,
            'password' => $mongo_user_password,
        ]));
$options = [
            "projection" => ["overall" => 1, "tempid" => 1, "temp_title" => 1],
            'skip'       => intval($postArr['start']),
            'limit'      => intval($postArr['length']), // to speed up operation which skip perform traversing all docs
            'sort'       => [$sortField => $sortOrder],
            'collation'  => ['locale' => 'en_US', "numericOrdering" => true], // for string as a number sorting
        ];
        // pr($options);die;
        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($match, $options);
        // $manager        = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://yoururl');
        $readPreference = new MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference::RP_PRIMARY);
        $cursor         = $this->manager->executeQuery('dbname.collection', $query, $readPreference);
```

Comment: yes I have learned this link but there are very few words described but I want all operator where define in a single pipeline

Comment: Pipeline is a sequence of stages one after other, your this question is not relevant with the main question you had asked. If so, you can post new question with inputs and outputs. Once check my edit portion of answer for single stage pipeline application